# Android reveal animation on FAB to launch a new activity

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, floating-action-button

I am trying to create a reveal animation on a Floating Action Button, so that when clicked it animates and starts a new activity. I haven't had any luck on finding a tutorial on how to do this specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a third party library like for example:
https://github.com/sergiocasero/RevealFAB.
This library is made for the purpose of your question and is easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error on this line:
 revealFAB.setOnClickListener(new RevealFAB.OnClickListener() {

as the OnClickListener() method has private access, what can I do?

Comment: I'm sorry but from this one line I can't tell what the problem is.